# Apache URL rewriting

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Say I have content in www.domain.com/products/

In the products folder, I have several html files all starting with "big-". For example:

```
big-product01.html
big-product02.html
```

How can I rewrite my URLs so that I could access these by typing:

```
www.domain.com/products/big/product01
www.domain.com/products/big/product02
...
```

Thanks in advance for any help on that!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (should not change the URL in the browser):

```
<Directory /var/www>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^products/big/(product[0-9][0-9]*)$ /products/big-$1.html [L]
</Directory>
```

If the `<Directory>` block has a relative path, you need a `RewriteBase` directive too.

Using [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) (will change the URL in the browser):

```
RedirectMatch permanent /products/big/(product[0-9][0-9]*)$ /products/big-$1.html
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution using mod_alias works. Not the one using mod_rewrite. Also I wish the URL would not change in the browser address bar after the rewriting. Have tried playing with your mod_rewrite solution without success until now.

Comment: Did you put the rewrite directives in a `<directory>` block (see my updated answer)? What does your `error.log` say about your failed attempts?

Comment: Thank you. Will try that. Not sure I understand the 'relative path' part. The root path seems to be /html/products. Checking right now with my provider to see how I can access that log file. Will report back later.

Comment: The [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) for the `RewriteBase` directive has an example.